# After upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04, my Broadcom STA Wireless driver is not working

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Broadcom Wireless card (BCM43XX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-card-bcm43xx)

I upgraded my HP DV5-1000US Laptop to Ubuntu 12.04. But I cannot get it connected to the Wireless. I went through the settings, Hardware, Additional Drivers and it says that "No proprietary drivers are in use on this system". Also it says "Broadcom STA Wireless Driver" is not activated. I tried to activate it after got my laptop connected to the net through a wired connection, but it says

> Sorry, installation of this driver failed.
>   
> Please have a look at the log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log