# Broadcom STA Wireless Driver failed install

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Broadcom Wireless card (BCM43XX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-card-bcm43xx)

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS using wubi.exe on my Dell Inspiron 1545 and I'm having some trouble getting my wireless to work properly. When I try to activate my Broadcom STA Wireless Driver, the installation fails. I am brand new to Ubuntu so I don't have much knowledge on how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to install "linux-headers":

1. Check what kernel version you are running:

   uname -r
2. install the right headers (if your version if a -generic):

   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic

Easiest to accomplish by plugging an Ethernet cable. Otherwise download and do as stated there: http://cross-lfs.org/view/svn/x86_64-64/final-system/linux-headers.html.

Here's a little more details: [After upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04, my Broadcom STA Wireless driver is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134926/)